# Extract portion of these urls with RegEx and c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have to check if these two url match a pattern (or 2, to be more accurate). If so, I'd like to extract some portion of data.

1) /selector/**en**/any-string-chain-you-want.aspx?FamiId=**32**

Then I need to extract "en" and "32" into variables. To me the regex expression should like roughly something like /selector/{0}/any-string-chain-you-want.aspx?FamiId={1}

2) /selector/**en**/F/**32**/any-string-chain-you-want.html

where en and 32 must be assigned into variables. So:
/selector/{0}/F/{1}/any-string-chain-you-want.html

{0}: 2 letters language code such as en, fr, nl, es,...
{1}: family id integers (2 or 3 numbers) such as 12, 38, 124, etc but not 1212

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance,

Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex:

```
/selector/([a-z]{2})/.+?\.aspx\?FamiId=([0-9]+)
```

Code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"/selector/([a-z]{2})/.+?\.aspx\?FamiId=([0-9]+)");
var test = "/selector/en/any-string-chain-you-want.aspx?FamiId=32";

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(test))
{
    var lang = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

    Console.WriteLine("lang: {0}, id: {1}", lang, id);
}
```

Regex for second case: `/selector/([a-z]{2})/F/([0-9]+)/.+?\.html` (code doesn't change)

Answer (score 1):

## Case 1

```
private const string Regex1 = @"/selector/(\w\w)/.+\.aspx?FamiId=(\d+)";
```

## Case 2

```
private const string Regex2 = @"/selector/(\w\w)/F/(\d+)/.+\.html";
```

## Usage

```
Match m = Regex.Match(myString, Regex2);
string lang = m.Groups[1].Value;
string numericValue = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this tutorial on [Regular Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx).

You could use the following expressions:

```
\/selector\/([a-z]{2})\/.*\.aspx\?FamiId=([0-9]{2,3})
```

and

```
\/selector\/([a-z]{2})\/F\/([0-9]{2,3})\/.*\.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Its useful to learn a bit of regular expression for cases like this.  [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is a free online RegEx building tool.  However, the most useful I have found is [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = @"/selector/en/any-string-chain-you-want.aspx?FamiId=32";
Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"/selector/(\w{2})/.+\.aspx\?FamiId=(\d{2,3})");
string result = String.Format(@"/selector/{0}/F/{1}/any-string-chain-you-want.html", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
^/.*?/(\w{2})/(?:F/|.*?FamiId=)(\d{2,3}).*$
```

It works for both urls.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like that

```
String urlSchema1= @"/selector/(<lang>\w\w)/.+\.aspx?FamiId=(<FamiId>\d+)";

Match mExprStatic = Regex.Match(inputString,urlSchema1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
 if (mExprStatic.Success || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mExprStatic.Value))
 {
    String language = mExprStatic.Groups["lang"].Value;
    String FamId = mExprStatic.Groups["FamId"].Value;
 }

String urlSchema2= @"/selector/(<lang>\w\w)/F/(<FamId>\d+)/.+\.html";

Match mExprStatic = Regex.Match(inputString,urlSchema2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
 if (mExprStatic.Success || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mExprStatic.Value))
 {
    String language = mExprStatic.Groups["lang"].Value;
    String FamId = mExprStatic.Groups["FamId"].Value;
 }
```